# unobtrusive JavaScript method that gets data from text file and writes it to HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax

I posted a thread about this earlier and have made some progress but now my code isn't working and I am not too sure why. I am attempting to use an unobtrusive JavaScript method that gets data from the provided text file (ajaxData.txt) and writes it to an element within the HTML. In this case, I am trying to write it to a button and have it display when the button is clicked.

This is for a homework assignment and I am NOT allowed to use any type of JavaScript library :(. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadXMLDoc(url){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById('A2').innerHTML=xmlhttp.statusText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxData.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Retrieve data from XML file</h2>

<p><b>Status text:</b><span id="A2"></span></p>

<button onclick="loadXMLDoc('ajaxData.txt')">Get XML data</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am still pretty new to JavaScript and especially new to AJAX so any type of help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What's not working? Any errors in your console?

Comment: xhr.send(null) is the crossbrowser version.

Comment: @harnish - I have no errors in firebug, I can't tell what exactly is going on?

Comment: @user1288091: does anything show up in the Net tab in firebug?

Comment: @user1288091 Ajax requests don't usually throw JavaScript errors when they fail, but you should be able to see the results, including the HTTP status and response text, of the request in the "Net" tab of Firebug.

Comment: Also, be sure to run this from an actual server ([XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)). Ajax and `file://` rarely get along.

Comment: I just tested your code exactly and it worked (FireFox 11/LAMP server).  Side note, "ajaxData.txt" isn't needed inside loadXMLDoc() as you specified it inside open().

Comment: @Gary - Thanks for all your help! I put it up on XAMPP and I am at least now getting something.

I am trying to get it to output the contents of 'ajaxData.txt' when the button is clicked, do you know how I might go about doing that?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I still can't get this working properly, I have a request for GET ajaxData.txt in the 'Net' tab of firebug. Can you tell me how I get this to display when clicking the button?

Comment: @user1288091 Make sure, not just that the request was made, but that it was successful -- a "Status" of "200 OK" and, if you expand the request to show details, it should have a tab containing the response text. If those are both good, then follow Elias' suggestion to output the response to the page.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I do see the Status of 200 OK but under 'Response' tab I see nothing, it is a blank white space. The file I am trying to import (ajaxData.txt) contains the text 'This is content retrieved from a text file!' so I am a bit confused...is there any small steps I could be missing that you can think of?

Comment: and I tried Elias' output file and nothing, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change...

```
xmlhttp.statusText
```

...to...

```
xmlhttp.responseText
```

Comment: statusText is a valid property.  As it stands, it will say "OK" instead of the contents of the file...  Although, the OP never said what the problem is (not working or it just saying "OK").

Comment: Gary, as he states, he wants to put the content of the txt file in an HTML element. His current code puts the word "Ok" in the html element, which is not his desired outcome.

Comment: Yeah, I rethought about it right after I commented.  Your response and my edit were about the same time.